# Simple keybind not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'm trying to bind <kbd>ctrl+x</kbd> to `editor.action.clipboardCutAction` (cut), but with the condition that it is only invoked when text is selected.

However, it is not working. It still cuts the whole line when no text is selected.

Code:

```
"key": "ctrl+x",
"command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
"when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && !editorReadonly"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Temporary solution

As a **temporary solution** you can reassign this shortcut first. For example:

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "workbench.action.closeMessages",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && !editorReadonly"
},
```

Instead of command `workbench.action.closeMessages`, you can use another.

## Disadvantage of temporary solution

If nothing is selected then pressing <kbd>ctrl+x</kbd> will execute first key combination and run `workbench.action.closeMessages` command.

## Alternative solution

In settings <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd> add following:

```js
// Controls whether copying without a selection copies the current line.
"editor.emptySelectionClipboard": false,
```

## Disadvantage of alternative solution

Also works when copying.

Answer (score 1):

An "official" answer has been developed by a member of the vscode team.  It is essentially what @Victor proposed.  See [disable Ctrl+X cut line when no selection](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122518#issuecomment-829321550):

> ctrl+x is just special and needs to be bound to a no-op to stop the
> default. I have added a `noop` command that does nothing. So the final
> solution would be:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "noop"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
    "when": "editorHasSelection"
}
```

Should be out in v1.56.