# Can you disable the cut line function of cut shortcut (Ctrl+X) in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If you have a selection, `cut` (Ctrl+X) will copy and delete the selection. If not, it will copy the whole line and delete it.

I want to disable the latter. It is close to `save` (Ctrl+S) and I don't want to delete my whole line when I want to save.

Can you disable the cut line function of `cut` shortcut (Ctrl+X) in VSCode?

#### What I have tried:

- Add `when` clause to `cut`: `editorHasSelection`:

  `Keyboard Shortcuts` menu looks like this:
  [image: Keyboard Shortcuts menu]

  My `keybindings.json`:

  ```json
  [
      {
          "key": "ctrl+x",
          "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
          "when": "editorHasSelection"
      },
      {
          "key": "ctrl+x",
          "command": "-editor.action.clipboardCutAction"
      }
  ]
  ```

  After saving and reopening VSCode, `cut` still works the same.
- Remove the second shortcut from `keybindings.json`:

  My `keybindings.json`:

  ```json
  [
      {
          "key": "ctrl+x",
          "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
          "when": "editorHasSelection"
      }
  ]
  ```

  `Keyboard Shortcuts` menu changes to:
  [image: Keyboard Shortcuts menu]

  After saving and reopening VSCode, `cut` still works the same.

#### Info

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Visual Studio Code version 1.55.2
- Recreated on Code - Insiders 1.56.0-insider (13f1aff, 2021-04-28T04:52:56.570Z)

Comment: Actually seems like a bug to me - that you can't disable `clipboardCutAction` in the obvious and correct way that you tried.  But see this answer for a solution that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48659458/836330 but the command he used isn't recognized anymore, perhaps use `notifications.clearAll` instead bound to `ctrl+x`.

Comment: @Mark This works! With `notifications.clearAll` works like a charm.

Comment: I made an issue but it is ignored into oblivion for now (9 hours and no response). https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122518

Comment: The vscode team is in the final testing for a new release next week so it may be awhile.

Comment: You should add the issue resolution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug which is now fixed and released as of 1.56.0 ([Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122518#issuecomment-829321550)).

**alexdima** from VSCode team's response is:

> `ctrl+x` is just special and needs to be bound to a no-op to stop the default.  I have added a `noop` command that does nothing.

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x",
        "command": "noop"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x",
        "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
        "when": "editorHasSelection"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: Set `editor.emptySelectionClipboard` to false. This will also disable Copy with no selection.

(Found it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/122518/files).)

Answer (score 0):

The first key binding that matches is used.

Define the Remove keybinding first

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x",
        "command": "-editor.action.clipboardCutAction"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+x",
        "command": "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
        "when": "editorHasSelection"
    }
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Regarding "Define the Remove keybinding first", I updated my question with more clarification on this.

Comment: It is true that the first keybinding that matches is used but it evaluates from the bottom up.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-rules

Comment: @pilgrim then use keyboard shortcut debugging to see what happens when you disable and ctrl+X and bind to a different key combo-when entry

Comment: @Mark ok, it bit strange but it is a method

Comment: @rioV8 I did the keybindings inspection thing and it doesn't match any command then but still cuts the entire line??   Something built-in is overriding the attempt to disable - that's why I think this is a bug.

Comment: @Mark Maybe there are hardcoded keybindings, asks for an vscode issue

Comment: @rioV8 That's possible, I will open one. (I got the same result as Mark)